# Django - How to filter out row that are same in some fields and differ in others?

Tags: python, django, django-models

i have a model in django like this

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    column_one = ForeignKey()
    column_two = ForeignKey()
    column_three = ForeignKey(null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["column_one", "column_two"],
                condition=Q(column_three=None),
                name='article_unique_if_no_column_three'),

            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["column_one", "column_two", "column_three"],
                condition=~Q(column_three=None),
                name='article_unique_if_column_three'),
        ]
```

How can i filter so that i get all the articles  but if there are two that have the same data except the `column_three`  it chose the one with `column_three` not null and exclude the one with `column_three=None`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can orderby and distinct

Example:

```
articles = Articles.objects.annotate(column_three_not_null=Q(column_three__isnull=False)
                                     ).order_by('column_one', 'column_two', 'column_three_not_null'
                                                ).distinct('column_one', 'column_two')
```

I haven't tested it, but I think it should work